# How to change bottombar icon on selection and unselection?

Tags: android, material-design

I have gone through this [link](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/blob/master/README.md) to implement bottombar.I want to change the icon when selected and unselected.

```
  mBottomBar.setOnMenuTabClickListener(new OnMenuTabClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuTabSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {
            if (menuItemId == R.id.bottomBarItemOne) {
                // The user selected item number one.
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMenuTabReSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {
            if (menuItemId == R.id.bottomBarItemOne) {
                // The user reselected item number one, scroll your content to top.
            }
        }
    });
```

By using menuItemId, I don't know how to change the selected icon. Please can someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to change the icon:

```
MenuItem item = (MenuItem) findViewById(menuItemId);
item.setIcon(aDrawable); // OR item.setIcon(aResourceId);
```

Comment: I am getting android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.view.MenuItem this error